# create a custom query to retrieve the email activity counts for the full previous month using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I created a PowerShell that interacts with Microsoft Graph API to gather email activity data (number of sent and received emails), and then post that information to a SharePoint list. This script works when I use a canned query api search such as [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityCounts(period='D7')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityCounts(period=%27D7%27)).

I'd like to create a custom query to retrieve the email activity counts for the full previous month, accounting for varying numbers of days. So say I run the script on the first of every month, I'd like to calculate the email count of the previous month. Here is the search arrangement.

$endDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$startDate = (Get-Date -Day 1 -Month (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Month -Year (Get-Date).Year).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$activityCountsUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityCounts(period='$startDate'..'$endDate')"

The error is "Invalid query string". I've tried multiple combinations and they all fail for the same reason.

```
$endDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$startDate = (Get-Date -Day 1 -Month (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Month -Year (Get-Date).Year).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$activityCountsUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityCounts(period='$startDate'..'$endDate')"

The error is "Invalid query string". I've tried multiple combinations and they all fail for the same reason.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getemailactivitycounts?view=graph-rest-1.0#function-parameters), the supported values for period are: D7, D30, D90, and D180, not a date range.